Difference between series cardinality on influxdb and prometheus
We are currently using influxdb 1.8 as our metrics store in our monitoring stack and are looking to see if the current stack can be moved to Prometheus.
One of the aspects that we are looking at is the series and measurement counts/cardinality.
On Influxdb 1.8 we look at numSeries (Series Cardinality) and numMeasurements (measurement count).
What I was trying to understand is what are the similar metrics in prometheus. Is prometheus_tsdb_head_series equivalent to seriesCardinality? Is there something for measurement count?
Another aspect is prometheus_tsdb_head_series is the count for active time series which I believe is in memory, but numSeries/numMeasurements guess is not in memory so these numbers are different.
The idea is, if when we load test to simulate a load of similar kind of data cardinality on prometheus, what "metrics/parameters" would be equivalent/analogous to measure influxdb vs Prometheus.
Can rate of pointReq (influxdb) be considered analogous to rate of prometheus_tsdb_head_samples_appended_total in prometheus?
(Directly comparing numSeries to prometheus_tsdb_head_series,for e.g makes Prometheus look very memory intensive consuming almost 3x the memory consumption, or is that how prometheus is designed to work?)
